# Current SSRS SubscriptionID into the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report which has got several email subscriptions scheduled. The report uses a stored procedure.

Whenever a report is run it checks if the `row_data` is present in the `table_A`. If it is not present it will email the data through the subscription, and then added it into a table.

Now the problem is, when the first subscription runs it will add the `row_data`. But when the second subscription will run it will check the `table_A` and find that `row_data` is already in `table_A`. The second and the following subscriptions will miss this `row_data`.

Is there a solution to this that all the subscriptions send exact same report? Merging all the subscription into one is not an option as the email list of each subscription has to be separate.

I have tried adding an additional column in table_A, to keep track of count of subscription run, but this solution fails when one of the subscription fails to run.

Maybe there is a way to get the current subscription id from `ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions.SubscriptionID` which is running the current instance of report, within the stored procedure. If this is possible I can use it, but I do not know how to get the current `subscriptionId` within the stored procedure or as a parameter. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure how much you can "cheat" but you could always a parameter "subscriptionID", probably a bad solution for any big corporation, but would work

Comment: Thank you Holmes, but how can I get current Subscription id into procedure? I do not have any idea, A sample code will be very helpful.